# Databricks Api: set Permissions for all Repos

Tags: databricks, databricks-repos, databricks-rest-api

The [databricks docu](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/permissions/set) allows to set permissions for specific repos such as:

```
PATCH /api/2.0/permissions/repos/{RepoID}
```

I would now set the permissions for all Repos. How can I do that? Simply removing the `repoID` leads to an error, in the UI it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change permissions on the `/Repos` folder, then that permissions will be inherited from it & propagated to all repositories. You can get object ID of that folder using [Get Status REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/workspace/getstatus), and then change permissions using the `/api/2.0/permissions/directories/<object_id>` REST endpoint.

P.S. it's better to use [Databricks Python SDK](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/sdk-python.html) instead of using REST API directly.